How can I tackle my parents opposing viewpoints?
I’m 20 years old and currently a university student and I am trying to find ways to improve the relationship I have with my parents through positive methods.
I’m quite happy when I’m in university but  I’m forced to go back home to them during vacations(to avoid paying the accommodation rent).My parents ideologies are quite different to mine on many things and sometimes I find our discussions quite distressing.
Firstly, I believe they live quite a materialistic life and are constantly discussing things like stocks, properties, markets and how to grow their wealth. They seem to have little interests besides this and expect me to be equally interested in their discussions. They are also quite conservative and I find some of their political views quite disturbing. I am interested in research and they comment often on my career choices and constantly try to encourage me to choose a more money-making career.
My views are quite different and I wish to live a simple lifestyle and aim to either help people or participate in curiosity-driven research.
The only thing I think which goes for me is that I’m a good student and I study at Cambridge which they pride themselves on. I think this prevents them from them getting more antagonistic towards me.
I’m not sure what to do in this situation. I see some good aspects in them and I believe they do love me but I dislike most of my interactions with them. I don’t want to completely cut them off and I have to go in the vacations anyway.I have tried speaking to them respectfully about my differences in opinions but it doesn’t seem to change them.
Thanks for any help.
Addendum: My goal in this scenario is to maintain some positive relationship with my parents and not having to resort to completely cutting them off to avoid the distress when interacting with them. I want to establish clear boundaries about what we can and can’t discuss and hopefully interact and discuss the few things we have in common. Based on the above context, what is the right way to achieve this?

Maybe start with the "Agree to disagree?" and then find topics you both can relate to.
